# JNDI LDAP returns nothing

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I have been stuck at a point for so long. I am trying to authenticate a user from an LDAP directory using LDAP via JNDI, but the code attached below returns nothing for "results" i.e. the search method (marked with **) returns null. I tried to debug the code, but did not understand what exactly is going on behind the "search" function of "DirContext" class. Can anybody help please?

```
public class Authenticate {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes", "unused" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        final String ldapAdServer = "ldap://iauth.tum.de:389/cn=someuser,ou=users,ou=data,ou=prod,ou=iauth,dc=tum,dc=de";
        final String ldapUsername = "cn=someuser,ou=users,ou=data,ou=prod,ou=iauth,dc=tum,dc=de";
        final String ldapPassword = "somepassword";
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
        if(ldapUsername != null) {
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUsername);
        }
        if(ldapPassword != null) {
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);
        }
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapAdServer);

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        **results = ctx.search("", "(objectClass=Person)", controls);**
        while (results.hasMoreElements()) 
        {
            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            Attribute attr = attributes.get("cn");
        }
    }
}
```

Since the search method of "DirContext" (marked in **), returns nothing, I can never enter the while loop. Can anybody tell where exactly I am being wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be searching an Active Directory instance. If that's the case (and even if it's not the issue may be the same), then the problem is not to do with your *search* code but with the initial setup. In particular, this line is at fault:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
```

Per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/auth.html), setting `SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION` to "none" performs an anonymous bind, meaning that to the LDAP directory your search request appears to be coming from an anonymous user. By default, Active Directory does not return an error when it gets an anonymous bind request, but the anonymous user does not normally have permissions to search the directory. To ensure that your context is created and bound to the appropriate identity, you should change the line in question to:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
```

Or even not set the `SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION` parameter at all, since it defaults to "simple".

Comment: Yes, I even tried "simple". But I receive an error saying "AuthenticationNotSupportedException" : [LDAP: error code 13 - Confidentiality Required]. What sort of confidentiality is required. I have tried the same credentials with Apache Directory Studion, and I am able to access from there, not from the API though.

Comment: "Confidentiality required" means you need to be using SSL. You can try changing your url to start with `ldaps://`. It may also be necessary to change the port in your LDAP url to 636 (the default LDAPS port).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I read about changing it to SSL on internet but nobody mentioned about changing the port number. It works finally. Thank you once again !!

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter to "(objectClass=*)" and see, otoh, you are using JNDI *not* Apache LDAP API like you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I am a bit new to this field. But anyhow changing the filter to the one you mentioned above, does not make any change.